# ASP.NET MVC 4 Breadcrumbs with dynamic list and parameters

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, breadcrumbs

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a list of breadcrumbs.  That list of dynamic (as you drill down to deeper pages the list of breadcrumbs grows) and most links have parameters.  I've seen examples with MVCSiteInfo but a little confused as most of the examples I've seen focus on a static set of links with no parameters.  I can't imagine this isn't a common problem so I was wondering what's the best way to accomplish this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Sieg

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm looking for something as well

Comment: Dreza, I've seen a lot of people using SiteMap.  It seems to do the job but looks pretty complex.  I opted to just simply have a section in the page that just filled in the pertinent links.  The layout page held the main ul tags for the list.  Just seemed simpler to me.

Comment: Cheers for that.  Yeah I've looked into sitemap and even used it a bit but have had heaps of issues on trying to get it to work so not sure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: I tried to use SiteMap too. But as approach with creating dynamic nodes has performance overhead, I start to look for static sitemap with dynamically set Title for current and parent nodes or write own breadcrumbs provider with blackjack etc.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest you use the [MVC Sitemap provider](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider/) and the bread crumb trails from it.  You will need to build a Dynamic Node Provider, but that's fairly straightforward - just follow [the steps to use Dynamic Nodes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps)

One of the tricks when building dynamic nodes is to make sure that you foreach across each node at each level, but add it to the nodes collection at the top.

```
        var nodes = new List<DynamicNode>();
        foreach (var eventCategory in eventCategories)
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode
                {
                    Key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", "home_events", eventCategory.Name),
                    ParentKey = "home_events",
                    Title = pluralize.Pluralize(eventCategory.Name),
                    Description = eventCategory.Description,
                    Controller = "event",
                    Action = "category"
                };
            node.RouteValues.Add("slug", eventCategory.Slug);
            nodes.Add(node);

            foreach (var e in eventCategory.Events)
            {
                var eventNode = new DynamicNode
                {
                    Key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", eventCategory.Name, e.Name),
                    ParentKey = node.Key,
                    Title = e.Name,
                    Controller = "event",
                    Action = "event"
                };
                eventNode.RouteValues.Add("categorySlug", eventCategory.Slug);
                eventNode.RouteValues.Add("slug", e.Slug);
                nodes.Add(eventNode);
            }
        }
```

and then it's just a case of putting the breadcrumbs in like this

```
Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

**home > events > marathons > melbourne marathon**